# Network configuration on a portable USB instance

Tags: boot, networking, usb, portable

I am looking at setting up a portable instance of Ubuntu 18.04; however after installation on my USB stick, I find I am left with no networking when plugging into a different computer than the on a ran the installation on.

I traced the issue to the default netplan YAML file under `/etc/netplan/`. This file (and the subsequent networkd files under `/run/systemd/network/`) are seemingly generated at install time; however they are defined for the wrong network interface.

Is there a way to have the OS setup network, each time on boot, to ensure that it starts with the correct interface definitions?

Comment: I don't think netplan is meant to do this smoothly. I think Network Manager is. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How would I use Network Manger? Are there any good wiki links?

Comment: Network Manager is installed by default in any desktop version of Ubuntu. I assume you are not running a server on a little USB key. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager You needn't start it from the command line or install it. It should already be there. Just click the NM icon at upper right.

Comment: Much appreciated